# Column Value Based On Value in Another Table

Tags: sql

So I have two Tables in my database, Table_1 and Table2.

Table_1 has three columns: First Name, Last Name, and Age.

Table_2 also has three columns: First Name, Last Name, and Age.

The only difference between the tables is that the Age column in Table_2 does not contain any data. What I am trying to do is put a search / query into the Age column of Table_2 that will search for the First Name value in Table_1, and if it finds that name in Table_1 then display that value in the Age column of Table 2.

```
Table_1

First Name  Last Name   Age

John        Smith       30        
David       Smith       30        
James       Smith       40        

Table_2

First Name  Last Name   Age

John        Smith       (Will return 30)       
David       Smith       (Will return 30)  
James       Smith       (Will return 40)
```

Is this done in some way by making the column computed?

Comment: which dbms you use

Answer (score 2):

You could join the two tables:

```
SELECT    table2.firstname, table2.lastname, table1.age
FROM      table2
LEFT JOIN table1 ON table1.firstname = table2.firstname AND 
                    table1.lastname  = table2.lastname
```

Comment: That would only join in a query is that correct ? What I wanted is for that value to stay in Table_2 permanently so the data is always there (if that makes sense ?). To be clearer, what I need is for that column to always hold a search function so that when new data is uploaded into the table it will automatically search for the relevent value in Table_1...

Comment: @AdsMont why do you need it persisted in table2? What not query it when you need it (or use a view for simplicity's sake)?

Comment: I need it to be persisted as the value that is returned is used for calculations in another column, so the value must always be there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that value to stay in table2 permanently then you can update it from table 1 using following query: (It only works for MSSQL)

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.age = t1.age
FROM table2 t2    
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.firstname = t2.firstname AND t1.lastname  = t2.lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use mysql database then update query should be like below

```
    UPDATE table2 a 
    JOIN table1 b ON a.firstname = b.firstname 
    AND a.lastname = b.lastname         
    SET a.age = b.age
```

But for postgreSQL it would be

```
UPDATE table2 a
SET a.age = b.age
FROM table1 b
WHERE a.firstname = b.firstname 
        AND a.lastname = b.lastname ;
```